# How can I refactor this Vue checktree composable to be more performant

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Currently I'm trying to make a Vue 3 composable for making a headless recursive checkbox tree view.
The checktree only selects leaf nodes, and the state of the internal nodes is always based on how many leaf nodes are selected.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-leu5hm?file=src%2FdataItems.ts,src%2FCheckTree.vue,src%2FCollapseItem.vue,src%2FuseCheckTree.ts,src%2FApp.vue

However the problem I'm running into is that performance when checking an item can be extremely slow, especially in dev mode (easily 3 seconds to select 1 checkbox). In the stackblitz example I added 100 rows each with about 35 sub rows of data. As you can see when the user checks a box, the entire transformed data is looped over again. This recursive loop itself is quite a heavy performance penalty as well as the subsequent rerenders for the component.

Is there a way to make this more efficient? I would really appreciate any input.

Comment: One of the reasons it's slow is because you're using `<Collapse />`. In order to know the height to animate to, it renders the contents at all times (including when closed). You might want to create a wrapper which only renders the contents a `tick` before opening the `<Collapse />` and removes it after finishing the close animation. Not rendering ~10.5k DOM elements, including 3.5k checkbox inputs, should make a difference. That's probably not the only problem, but i'd say it's the biggest.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the destructure operations, particularly in loops. It also looks like you can avoid lots of transformations. Here is an example, your `getCheckedTriState()`.

Here, you recursively build objects from the `leafNodes` array, then create a new object to override some properties' value, and then build an array from just those entries with a `true` value:

```
function getCheckedTriState(leafNodes: TDataItem[]) {
  const totalLeafNodeIds = leafNodes.reduce((key, value) => ({ ...key, [value.id]: false }), {});
  const allNodes = { ...totalLeafNodeIds, ...internalCheckedModel.value };
  const unCheckedLeafNodes = Object.entries(allNodes).filter(([_, value]) => value === false).map(([key]) => key);

  if (unCheckedLeafNodes.length === 0) return true; // checked
  if (unCheckedLeafNodes.length === Object.keys(totalLeafNodeIds).length) return false; // unchecked
    return null; // indeterminate
};
```

But you can just count the number of selected leafs and compare it with the number of available leafs:

```
function getCheckedTriState(leafNodes: TDataItem[]) {
  const countUnchecked = leafNodes.reduce((countUnchecked, dataItem) => 
    !internalCheckedModel.value[dataItem.id] ? countUnchecked+1 : countUnchecked
  , 0)

  if (countUnchecked === 0) return true; // checked
  if (countUnchecked === leafNodes.length) return false; // unchecked
    return null; // indeterminate
};
```

Or even simpler:

```
function getCheckedTriState(leafNodes: TDataItem[]) {
  if (leafNodes.length === 0) return false
  const firstIsChecked = internalCheckedModel.value[leafNodes[0].id]
  const nodesHaveSameState = leafNodes.every(node => internalCheckedModel.value[node.id] === firstIsChecked)
  return nodesHaveSameState ? firstIsChecked : null;
}
```

Note that I am re-engineering your code, I might miss details about your data structure. For example, I assume that `internalCheckedModel` does not contain keys that are not ids in `leafNodes`, and that the values of `internalCheckedModel` are all boolean values. If this is not accurate, you would have to adjust accordingly.

In the end, you will have to fix your code yourself anyway, my hope is that comparing the three functions will give you an idea what to look for.

---

If you want to reduce the number of re-renderings, have a look at the [`v-memo`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-memo) directive, I think the example in the documentation is pretty close to what you need.

Comment: Thank you, your tip definitely sped it up quite a bit. Do you maybe also have an idea about how to prevent unnecessary component re-renders? Preferably this extra logic would live inside the composable itself

Comment: That's great! Have a look at the [`v-memo`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-memo) directive, I think the example in the documentation is pretty close to what you need.